# Particles spawn too fast - Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, game-development

I am trying to make a snow effect behind the main menu of my game using the particle emitter but particles spawn way too fast.

I have this code:

```js
       var particles = this.add.particles('snow');

        var emitter = particles.createEmitter({
            speedY: { min: 15, max: 40 },
            gravityY: 0,
            scale: 0.2,
            quantity: 1,
            lifespan: { min: 28000, max: 30000 },
            emitZone: { source: new Phaser.Geom.Line(-20, -100, 820, -100 )}
       });
```

And quantity is only one, so I do not know how to fix this. Is it possible to change the spawn speed of the particles?

I am using Phaser 3 and the arcade physics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [frequency](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Particles.ParticleEmitter.html#frequency__anchor) setting.

It doesn't exactly change the spawn speed, but it changes the time between flow cycles. If you add a `frequency: 1000` to the emitter you currently have, it gives you about 8-10 particles on the screen at a time. You can play with that number until you get the flow you want.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved for my snow effect this way, maybe it helps you. It has a random wind blow and rotation for the snowflakes.

```
this.emitter = snowParticles.createEmitter({
    frame: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    x: {min: 0, max: this.sys.game.canvas.width},
    y: 0 ,
    lifespan: {min: 20000, max: 60000},
    speedY: 50,
    gravityX: Math.ceil((Math.random() - 0.5) * 2) < 1 ? -10 : 10,
    gravityY: 10,
    minVelocityY: 10,
    maxVelocityY: 30,
    minVelocityX: 10,
    maxVelocityX: 30,
    quantity: 1,
    scale: 0.4,
    frequency: 1000,
    blendMode: 'ADD',
    rotate: { start: 0, end: 180 }
});
```

Here is the uploaded live example: https://vajda.co.uk/demo/react/winter-landscape/